# Canvas Path using offset make to many copies (onDraw running twice)

Tags: android, canvas, path, offset

seems I have a problem to understand how offset works. When I use the code below it create me 5 arrowheads, but why? I create one and the use twice offset. So i thought i get 3 arrow heads.

```
public class legende extends View {

    private Paint paint;
    private Path arrowPath;

    public legende(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        paint = new Paint();
        arrowPath = new Path();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = 1500;
        int height = 5000;
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);


        arrowPath.moveTo(420, 300);
        arrowPath.lineTo(430, 300);
        arrowPath.lineTo(420, 310);
        arrowPath.lineTo(410, 300);
        arrowPath.close();
        canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, paint);


        arrowPath.offset(0,200);
        canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, paint);

        arrowPath.offset(0,380);
        canvas.drawPath(arrowPath, paint);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Looks like, the problem is, that onDraw is called twice, but i don't know why.
This is how I use it in my fragment activity:

```
            hScrollView.addView(new legende(getActivity()));
            scrollView.addView(hScrollView);
            relativeLayout.addView(scrollView);
```

Comment: Edit the question, seems like the problem is that onDraw is called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you´ve got a non thread safe implementation of the `onDraw` method.

This guy worked it out by using a thread safe implementation: [Custom View not drawing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097173/custom-view-not-drawing-properly?noredirect=1#comment48343483_30097173)

Maybe you should [copy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#Path(android.graphics.Path)) the path to a local object inside the `onDraw` and then alter and paint.