# Custom View not drawing properly

Tags: android, canvas, view, path, ondraw

I am making an Android game which has a board with some squares (similar to a chess board). Each square has some colors and I made a custom `View` class in which I overrided the `onDraw()` method in order to draw the square in the way I want to. Each square is composed of four triangles, as you can see in the next picture, in which a board with 3x3 squares is shown:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48529299/Impossible%20Puzzle/ic_launcher.png
Each triangle can be of one of three colors: purple, pink or yellow.
My `onDraw()` method draws each of the triangles and the issue is that sometimes I see white or black triangles. That should be impossible as my custom `View` class only can draw with the three colors I mentioned earlier. It has an static array called `availableColors` which I am sure does not contain either black or white color, so if this happens is because I am doing something bad on the `onDraw()` method. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?
Here is my custom `View` subclass:

```
package bembibre.impossiblepuzzle.ui;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Path.FillType;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;
import bembibre.impossiblepuzzle.R;
import bembibre.impossiblepuzzle.logic.models.Square;

public class ImpossiblePuzzleView extends View {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();
    private static int[] availableColors;
    private Square square;

    public ImpossiblePuzzleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        if (ImpossiblePuzzleView.availableColors == null) {
            ImpossiblePuzzleView.availableColors = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.available_colors);
        }
        this.paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        this.paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        this.path.setFillType(FillType.WINDING);
    }

    /**
     * Devuelve un color en formato #RRGGBB de entre los colores que están
     * disponibles en el juego para pintar los cuadrados del tablero.
     * 
     * @param index un número entero mayor que 0.
     * 
     * @return un color en formato #RRGGBB.
     */
    public int getColor(int index) {
        int result;

        index--;
        if ((index > 0) && (index < ImpossiblePuzzleView.availableColors.length)) {
            result = ImpossiblePuzzleView.availableColors[index];
        } else {
            result = ImpossiblePuzzleView.availableColors[0];
        }

        return result;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (this.square != null) {
            switch(this.square.getType()) {
            case NORMAL:
                int full = this.getMeasuredWidth();
                int half = full / 2;
                int[] status = this.square.getStatus();

                this.path.reset();
                this.paint.setColor(this.getColor(status[0]));
                this.path.moveTo(half, half);
                this.path.lineTo(0, 0);
                this.path.lineTo(0, full);
                this.path.lineTo(half, half);
                this.path.close();
                canvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);

                this.path.reset();
                this.paint.setColor(this.getColor(status[1]));
                this.path.moveTo(half, half);
                this.path.lineTo(0, 0);
                this.path.lineTo(full, 0);
                this.path.lineTo(half, half);
                this.path.close();
                canvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);

                this.path.reset();
                this.paint.setColor(this.getColor(status[2]));
                this.path.moveTo(half, half);
                this.path.lineTo(full, 0);
                this.path.lineTo(full, full);
                this.path.lineTo(half, half);
                this.path.close();
                canvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);

                this.path.reset();
                this.paint.setColor(this.getColor(status[3]));
                this.path.moveTo(half, half);
                this.path.lineTo(full, full);
                this.path.lineTo(0, full);
                this.path.lineTo(half, half);
                this.path.close();
                canvas.drawPath(this.path, this.paint);
                break;

            case UNTOUCHABLE:
            default:
                Drawable background;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
                    background = this.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.untouchable);
                } else {
                    background = this.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.untouchable, null);
                }
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
                    this.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
                } else {
                    this.setBackground(background);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Indica a esta vista cuál es el cuadrado que tiene que mostrar, es decir,
     * qué es lo que tiene que pintar.
     * 
     * @param square objeto que indica a esta vista cómo se tiene que pintar.
     */
    public void setSquare(Square square) {
        this.square = square;
    }
}
```

Comment: I may be wrong but I´d suggest you to pretty your code a bit and it may fix your problem. You´re overlapping points by adding 4 vertices to builda  triangle so call close without adding the last one (redundant with the first). And use always the same rotation order, for example, clockwise. See that the first one you´re drawing is counterclockwise.

Comment: Are you sure all colors are colors and not black or alpha?

Comment: I will remove the last vertice of each triangle and I will use the same rotation for each triangle and see what happens. The error is very difficult to repeat so it will take pretty much time...

Comment: Colors are well, the problem is not at the colors.

Comment: I think that when I make the call setBackground() I am generating an infinite loop. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: it´d crash if so... You´d notice if such was the case because of the StackOverflow exception

Comment: I fixed the infinite loop and did what you said but I am still getting the same problem. Sometimes one of the triangles does not get painted, unless I have checked that colors are correct. The problem happens with a very little frecuency.

Comment: which triengle? left, top, rght or bottom?

Comment: anyway... what if the problems has to do with two threads accessing the `path`. Could you define the var inside the `onDraw()` or, even, having 4 prefixed paths so no thread would call a reset while you´re drawing...

Comment: This error has happened with several of the triangles, not only one. Last time I saw it was the bottom triangle. It was completely white. I will try what you said. Nevertheless, I think that most of the times the triangle which does not get painted is the bottom triangle, the last triangle to be painted.

Comment: I chose the solution of having 4 prefixed paths which are initialized on the constructor of my custom `View`. I cant reproduce the error, but it used to happen with very little frecuency, so I do not know if this solution has fixed the error or if the error continues. When the error happened, the bottom triangle was not drawn, but I do not know why.

Comment: Aaaaah... Ye of little faith!! The randomness points to the second thread...

Comment: That sounds weird because in one of my tests I made `onDraw()` synchronized, so if the second Thread changed the `Path` then the first has already finished drawing in the canvas. Yet with the method synchronized I could see that the error happened again. This is making me slightly crazy...